# ROLE_ANONYMOUS gives me a blank 500 page

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I'm using spring-security-core 2.0-RC2 in my grails 2.3.5 app.  When I'm assigned the AnonymousUser token and try to access a page that is for a different ROLE (ie ROLE_ADMIN), I get greeted with a blank white page and an HTTP error code of 500.

Nothing shows up in grails logs.  No exceptions.  The page like I mentioned is blank and does not even show grail's normal 500 page.

If I change the roles allowed to ROLE_ANONYMOUS, the page renders fine.

What am I missing???

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug, I changed the way that anonymous users work in 2.0. If you want, create a small test app that demonstrates the problem and run `grails bug-report`. Attach that generated zip to an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE and I'll take a look.

Comment: it seems to only happen when used in conjunction with cookie-session plugin.  otherwise it does not happen.